# Regex, multiple occurences within selection

Tags: regex

I'm fairly good with regex, but I have a problem that I don't seem to be able to wrap my head around.

In a document, I want to replace all occurences of a text that is between 2 tags, but not replace them outside of the tags.

The tags I want to replace are ][, and only if they are within { }. The amount of ][ is unknown. Can be 1, 2 or even 7.

Here is an example:

```
This is a tilte ][
And here some data {[tag1][tag2][tag3][tag4]}
This is another tilte ][
And here some data {[tag1][tag2][tag3][tag4]}
```

Lets say I want to replace the ][ to , with regex when it is between { and }. How do I do that?

It would obvously be this:

```
{.+?\]\[.+?}
```

but that only replaces the first time. I don't want to run it 20 times hoping that it is 20 or less times.

I'm using Notepad++

Comment: I don't think that this can be done in native notepad++. You might be able to script it though, using [Python Script - Plugin for Notepad++](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) - "Full regular expression support for search and replace - script Python regular expression replaces" - so presumably a while loop check for the search string if found replace stop when no search string found (very basic pseudo code ;))

Comment: Of course you have to know python ... I don't.

Comment: have you check  `. matches newline` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^.*?\{|\G(?!^)).*?\K]\[`
- Replace with: `,`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:           # non capture group
  ^             # beginning of line
    .*?         # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    \{          # opening curly brace
  |           # OR
    \G          # restart from previous match position
    (?!^)       # negative lookahead, not at the beginning of line
)             # end group
.*?           # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
\K            # forget all we have seen until this position
]\[           # closing and opening square bracket
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: I think this is what I'm after... I will have time to play with this in about 30 minutes... Aside from the +1, I'll also mark it as anwered if it is indeed what I need, but I think it is. :) So thank you for your answer on beforehand. :)

Comment: Awesome. In what I need to do, it doesn't work 100%, but it'll give me enough knowledge now to sort it out. You earned youself a check. :)

Comment: @LPChip: You're welcome, glad it helps. Could you show me the few% that don't work?

Comment: @LPChip please add  into you example, the few that does not work

Comment: Well, I wrote here { ... ][ ... } to make things easier to work with, but I actually used [TAGS][...][...][/TAGS] in which case you get a problem with [/TAGS]. But I solved it by just doing a regex replace on all [TAGS]...[/TAGS] to {...} and then it works correctly.